# Unknown CSS issue- Divs won't stack and I've lost all perspective as to why that might be

Tags: jquery, css

Here is the example fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/k3bmN/3/

I intended to have the purple colored object fit inside of the yellow colored box (effectively covering it up) while the jquery UI buttons float on top of the whole 'window' I've made. The menu tab and buttons should float over the object.

I'm instead having issues even getting the divs to stack. Black is #main and the object is being pushed outside of it

[image]

```
<div id='main'>
    <div id='foo' class='abox'>
        <div class='boxholder'>
            <div class='menutab' onClick='menutog(this)'></div>
            <div class='buttons'>
                <label for='drag'>Drag</label>
                <input id='drag' type='checkbox'></input>
                <label for='size'>Size</label>
                <input id='size' type='checkbox'></input>
                <label for='chat'>Chat</label>
                <input id='chat' type='checkbox'></input>
                <label for='close'>Close</label>
                <input id='close' type='checkbox'></input>
            </div>
            <object class='ttvvideo'></object>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

#main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
.abox {
    width: 320px;
    height: 178px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
.boxholder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.menutab {
    float: left;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 21px;
    background-color: #6441a5;
    z-index: 2;
}
.buttons {
    font-size: .55em;
    margin-left: 27px;
}
.ttvvideo {
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

Comment: I feel like .button() and/or .buttonset() are the culprit. I've been staring at this too long to be of more use. Save me, please.

Comment: Add `position: absolute` to `.ttvvideo`.  You'll also need to change the order of the `<object>` so that it renders behind your menu. (http://jsfiddle.net/k3bmN/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkr8e/1/) is what you are looking for. Add `position: absolute` to `.buttons` and `.menutab`.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `<object class='ttvvideo'></object>` in buttons `div`.

```
 <div class='buttons'>
                <label for='drag'>Drag</label>
                <input id='drag' type='checkbox'></input>
                <label for='size'>Size</label>
                <input id='size' type='checkbox'></input>
                <label for='chat'>Chat</label>
                <input id='chat' type='checkbox'></input>
                <label for='close'>Close</label>
                <input id='close' type='checkbox'></input>
                <object class='ttvvideo'></object>
 </div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k3bmN/6/)

Answer (score 0):

`top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom`, & `z-index` [have no effect on non-positioned elements (link Mozilla Developer for `top`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top). So, set `position:absolute;` on `.ttvvideo`, `.menutab`, & `.buttons` and give `.buttons` a high `z-index as well to push it above everything.

```
.menutab {
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 21px;
    background-color: #6441a5;
    z-index: 2;
}
.buttons {
    font-size: .55em;
    margin-left: 27px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:50;
}
.ttvvideo {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/k3bmN/7/

Comment: Why `.ttvvideo { position: absolute }`?

Comment: @ShadowCat7 Fair point, it's not necessary since `position: absolute` on the other two elements forced `.ttvvideo` to the top anyways (technically `top: 0px` is also not needed), I just did it so all elements are positioned. Easier for future development, depending on how the site proceeds.